# PHP PDO Inserting multiple select data

Tags: php, pdo

I am not good with programming and english, and I'm 40++ .I have few questions about PHP PDO and Multi Select stuff..

I've created a multi select menu in a form, which invoke the value from database like this:-

```
<select multiple=multiple id="imsohot">

<?php

echo '<option value="$row[id]">';

?>

</select>
```

and It works fine.

I also created a new file to process the form to submit the data to database and it worked for normal database insertion, and it look something like this :-

```
$qry="query goes here";

stmt=conn->prepare($qry);

stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['varname']);

stmt->execute();
```

My Question is:
But how do I submit values into database when it doesn't have fixed array? like to submit the `#imsohot` multiselect menu when certain data is selected.

And regarding my question, which of these 2 links would solve my problem?

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is neither :)

To save your data to the database using PDO, you must first prime your SQL statement. [This example of PDO::exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php#100850) shows what you're trying to do.

Notice how it runs through **PDO::prepare()** and **PDO::execute()** using a **while loop.** All you need to do is use your form's data where he passes **$data** in.

HTH :)

Comment: Thank you, this going to take sometime to understand.